# Textarea placeholder not working on blur in Chrome for Mac

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a problem with the textarea element in Chrome for Mac.
Specifically, it does not revert to the original placeholder when a user clicks outside of it.

This is how it's working right now:

[image: This is how it's working]

And this is how it should work:

[image: And this is how it should work]

Comment: Please post the fiddle

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/o98gb34r/)**

[image]

css

```
textarea:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder 
{
    color: transparent;
}
textarea:focus::-moz-placeholder{
    color: transparent;
}
textarea:focus:-moz-placeholder{
    color: transparent;
}
input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder 
{
    color: transparent;
}
input:focus::-moz-placeholder{
    color: transparent;
}
input:focus:-moz-placeholder{
    color: transparent;
}
```

html

```
<input placeholder="I am an input" />
<input placeholder="I am an input" />
<input placeholder="I am an input" />

<textarea placeholder="I am a textarea" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
```

Comment: Is this tested in Chrome on a Mac? :)

Comment: The ::input-placeholder pseudo-element is currently supported in Firefox 4+, Chrome 4+, Safari 5+, Opera 11.6 and IE10. Firefox supports both a pseudo-element and a pseudo-class for older versions of Firefox.